# Using ffmpeg in microsoft Visual studio ( 2008 )

Tags: .net, visual-c++, ffmpeg

how can i use ffmpeg functions with my Microsoft VS? i know i have to use MSYS and MingGW, but there is any document show the steps.

Answer (score 0):

See [FFmpeg Documentation - Windows](http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Windows):

```
4. Windows

    4.1 Native Windows compilation using MinGW or MinGW-w64
    4.2 Microsoft Visual C++
        4.2.1 Linking to FFmpeg with Microsoft Visual C++
    4.3 Cross compilation for Windows with Linux
    4.4 Compilation under Cygwin
    4.5 Crosscompilation for Windows under Cygwin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use from your C++ app, you can quick-start with already pre-built binaries. Have a look at the question describing the details: [Use FFmpeg in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio)

You however tagged the question as [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) so I suppose you might prefer .NET wrapper instead: [Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to build ffmpeg with MSVC, but it is possible to build MSVC programs that link in the FFmpeg methods.  See here for details:

http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=MSVC

Comment: "There is nothing here anymore! This page was outdated, and its content removed to prevent people from wasting their times with it."