# How to read frames from a video as bitmaps in UWP

Tags: .net, video, ffmpeg, uwp

Is it possible to load a video and extract single frames from it (as images) in Universal Windows Applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two namespaces that allow you to get frames:

1. "Windows.Media.Capture" namespace. Use it if you want to capture video from camera then read "Process media frames with MediaFrameReader" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader
2. "Windows.Media.Playback" namespace. Use it if you want to get frames from file or stream video. Scroll to paragraph "Use MediaPlayer in frame server mode" on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to load a video and extract single frames from it (as images) in Universal Windows Applications?

You can use [MediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.getthumbnailasync.aspx) to get an image stream from the video. Then you can use [RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh701831.aspx) to convert the [IInputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.aspx) to [InMemoryRandomAccessStream](http://InMemoryRandomAccessStream). We can add the IRandomAccessStream to set [BitmapSource.SetSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource.aspx).

For example:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Video)
    {
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
    }
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    var thumbnail = await GetThumbnailAsync(file);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(thumbnail, randomAccessStream);
    randomAccessStream.Seek(0);
    bitmapImage.SetSource(randomAccessStream);
    MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;
}

public async Task<IInputStream> GetThumbnailAsync(StorageFile file)
{
    var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
    var mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
    mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);
    return await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
}

internal class FileExtensions
{
    public static readonly string[] Video = new string[] { ".mp4", ".wmv" };
}
```