# uwp highresolution Thumbnail

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp, thumbnails

I am trying to put the Thumbnail of video files on bigger xaml elements like : background Image of a page or grid or a top banner on the page. and in this case the normal thumbnail I am getting from following code. does look good because they are low resolution.

```
var imgSource = await MyVideoFile.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView, 200, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale)
```

I want high resolution Thumbnails. Should I extract out the frames of the video file as Bitmap Images and use them? or is therea way of getting a high resolution Thumbnail of a specific size?

Comment: If your custom have a high resolution screen that you can use ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale to get the high resolution thumbnails.

Comment: I am already using UseCurrentScale as you can see in the code I provided

Comment: But your screen  is not high resolution.

Comment: Can you use ffmpeg?

Comment: yes my screen resolution is 1366 x 720 , thumbnails look fine in small image elements on my screen but look bad on bigger elements, how can I get a high resolution image, which I can only use on the larger elements? and which looks good on all screen resolutions?

Comment: yes I am developing uwp app so I might be able to use ffmpeg I guess

Comment: I think you also can change the Image resolution.

Comment: I also find another method to get the  `Thumbnail` :`mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync`.See:https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314446/6116637

Comment: yes but that method gives us the video frame, isnt there a way to get thumbnail from thumbnailAsync with high resolution?

Comment: I think you can change the Image resolution.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I only know how to do in wpf. UWP have no Bitmap.In wpf ,you can use `Bitmap.SetResolution`

Comment: @lindexi Take a look at [`WriteableBitmapEx`](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) if you want a replacement for `Bitmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I extract out the frames of the video file as Bitmap Images and use them?or is therea way of getting a high resolution Thumbnail of a specific size?

It's dependent on your requirement. But according to your description, you might do not need to do this.

I checked your code. You've set a fixed value 200 as `requiredSize`. Please read the document of [`GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode, UInt32, ThumbnailOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile#methods_) method. It shows:

> The requested size, in pixels, of the longest edge of the thumbnail. Windows uses the requestedSize as a guide and tries to scale the thumbnail image without reducing the quality of the image.

It means the "requiredSize" should be the StorageItemThumbnail object's original width. Then, in your original post, you said:

> I am trying to put the Thumbnail of video files on bigger xaml elements like : background Image of a page or grid or a top banner on the page.

If the xaml element's size is much more larger than the StorageItemThumbnail object's original size,then it always will look bad.

So, I suggested that you could pass a dynamic "requiredSize" to the `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync` method by the bigger element's size, then it would return a thumbnail with a proper resolution for you.

For example:

```
var imgSource = await MyVideoFile.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView, bigelement.Width, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale)
```

In the end, the document also says:

> If Windows can't find a thumbnail image that it can scale to meet the requested size, a larger thumbnail might be returned. If no larger thumbnail is available, a thumbnail image that is smaller than the requested size might be returned.

If you're in this scenario, you could think about extracting out the frames of the video file as Bitmap Images like you said.