# Getting Frames from Video File with MediaComposition and IBasicVideoEffect

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to process video file frame by frame. I don't need to save frames to image.

There are some Q&A ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301248/how-to-read-frames-from-a-video-as-bitmaps-in-uwp)) about this topic. But [MediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.getthumbnailasync) is slooow. There is also [FFmpeg UWP](https://github.com/ffmpeginteropx/FFmpegInteropX) project with frame grabber, but is also not very fast...

So I took advantage of custom [IBasicVideoEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects), that implements method for processing every frame (`ProcessFrame`). Which is exactly what I need. The problem here is, that I have no clue how to evoke `ProcessFrame` method. Only idea is to play video in MediaPlayerElement or save composition with effect to file. But I need to process video file fast, on the background, without replay, without rendering another file.

Here is the solution with rendering file (faster frame grabber so far...)

```
//Page.Loaded
private async void LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //set file to process
    StorageFile videoFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("big_buck_bunny.mp4");

    //create clip from file
    MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);

    //apply "effect" on clip
    var vefdef = new VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(VideoEffectReachFrames).FullName);
    clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(vefdef);

    //create composition
    compositor = new MediaComposition();
    compositor.Clips.Add(clip);
}

MediaComposition compositor;

private async void Button_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //create temp file 
    var tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("tempFile.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    //HERE - I need to render file.
    await compositor.RenderToFileAsync(tempFile);//render to file to evoke VideoEffect..
}
```

And `ProcessFrame` method in Effect class:

```
public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
{
    //Getting pixel data, I am fine here

    var inputFrameBitmap = context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
    var frameSize = inputFrameBitmap.PixelWidth * inputFrameBitmap.PixelHeight * 4;

    var frameBuffer = new Buffer((uint)frameSize);
    context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(frameBuffer);
    var framePixels = frameBuffer.ToArray();

    Debug.WriteLine($"Touching 25th red pixel {framePixels[100]}");
}
```

[Whole UWP project](https://github.com/tesar-tech/reach-frames-uwp/tree/master).

How to reach frames with help of `MediaComposition` without unnecessary file render ?

Comment: Hi, this kind of rendering is necessary. It needs to be converted from a byte stream into an image, and the images must be serialized into a video. Although it is not displayed in the background, the application still needs to render

Comment: I am basically looking just for the "converted from byte stream into an image"... Isn't there a way how to use just that part of the process?

Comment: I don't quite understand your intention. In fact, the byte stream itself is an image. If you render a byte stream (such as converting it to a `BitmapImage` as the source of the Image control), it will be displayed as an image. If you save the byte stream as a file, it is an image file (depending on the file type, encoding may be required)

Comment: My intention is get that byte stream (image). Problem is I need to render video to file to obtain individual frames of video (in ProcessFrame method). There has to be some way how to do it... I just didn't found it, I guess..

Comment: Hi, Currently this process may be necessary, you need to encode the byte stream into a picture before processing. You can delete temporary pictures after processing is complete

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Win32 Media Foundation API by implementing a C++ UWP Runtime Component and referencing it on your C# UWP project.
Also there is the *SharpDX.MediaFoundation* library which is a wrapper into this API for C#.

For example using the `SourceReader` class with the `SourceReader.ReadSample` method to obtain the bytes for the frame.

Reference:

http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/mediafoundation/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk?redirectedfrom=MSDN