# How can i extract frames from video using directshowlib-2005?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directshow

With this code i can play video files from my hard disk and show the video in `pictureBox1`. But i wonder how can i save all the frames of the video to images files on the hard disk ? While playing the video or without playing i need somehow to extract the frames and save them.

This is my used code so far:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        IGraphBuilder m_graphBuilder = null;
        IMediaControl m_mediaCtrl = null;
        IMediaEventEx m_mediaEvt = null;
        IMediaPosition m_mediaPos = null;
        IMediaSeeking m_mediaSeeking = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void InitInterfaces()
        {
            try
            {
                m_graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
                m_mediaCtrl = (IMediaControl)m_graphBuilder;
                m_mediaEvt = (IMediaEventEx)m_graphBuilder;
                m_mediaPos = (IMediaPosition)m_graphBuilder;
                m_mediaSeeking = (IMediaSeeking)m_graphBuilder;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't start directshow graph");
            }
        }


        void CloseInterfaces()
        {
            if (m_mediaCtrl != null)
            {
                m_mediaCtrl.StopWhenReady();
            }
            m_mediaCtrl = null;
            m_mediaEvt = null;
            m_mediaPos = null;

            m_mediaSeeking = null;

            if (m_graphBuilder != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.m_graphBuilder);
            m_graphBuilder = null;
        }   


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void SetuupVideoRenderer()
        {
            IBaseFilter vmrFilter = null;

            vmrFilter = (IBaseFilter)new VideoMixingRenderer();
            m_graphBuilder.AddFilter(vmrFilter, "Video Renderer");

            IVMRFilterConfig FilterConfig = (IVMRFilterConfig)vmrFilter;
            FilterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMRMode.Windowless);

            IVMRWindowlessControl windowlessCtrl = (IVMRWindowlessControl)vmrFilter;
            windowlessCtrl.SetVideoClippingWindow(this.pictureBox1.Handle);
            windowlessCtrl.SetVideoPosition(null, DsRect.FromRectangle(pictureBox1.ClientRectangle));
            windowlessCtrl.SetAspectRatioMode(VMRAspectRatioMode.LetterBox);

        }
        private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|mp4 (*.mp4)|*.mp4|mov (*.mov)|*.mov||";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                CloseInterfaces();
                InitInterfaces();

                SetuupVideoRenderer();
                m_graphBuilder.RenderFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, null);

                textBoxDur.Text = ( getDuration() * 0.0000001).ToString();
                m_mediaCtrl.Run();

                timer1.Enabled = true;

            }
        }

        private void GetPosition(out long CurrentPos,out long StopPos)
        {

            m_mediaSeeking.GetPositions(out CurrentPos, out StopPos);

        }
        private long getDuration()
        {
            long duration;
            m_mediaSeeking.GetDuration(out duration);

            return duration;

        }

        private void SetPos(double fPos)
        {
             DsLong startPosition = (DsLong)(10000000 * fPos); 

            m_mediaSeeking.SetPositions(startPosition, AMSeekingSeekingFlags.AbsolutePositioning, null, AMSeekingSeekingFlags.NoPositioning);


        }
        private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_mediaCtrl.Pause();
        }

        private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_mediaCtrl.Run();

        }
        private void OnVideoCompleted()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Video Playback Completed");
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long iCurPos, iStopPos;

            GetPosition(out iCurPos, out iStopPos);

            if (iCurPos >= iStopPos)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                OnVideoCompleted();
                return;
            }
            textBoxCurPos.Text = (iCurPos * 0.0000001 ).ToString();


        }

        private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetPos(Convert.ToDouble(textBoxNewPos.Text));
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried on ur own so far?

Comment: @L.Guthardt not much since i'm new to directshowlib. So far i just tried to check all the variables global variables like m_mediaSeeking and m_mediaPos but you can get only information with it. I also tried to make pictureBox1.Image.Save....inside a timer or when start playing but it seems not logic to play it and then save the images from the pictureBox1. if i have a video of an hour it will take a lot of time to save all frames.

Comment: @L.Guthardt Not sure even where to start. Let's say it's possible but i'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is excatly what you are looking for:
[extract frames of a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490116/c-sharp-extract-frames-from-part-of-a-video-file)

Have a look as well at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825677/extracting-frames-of-a-avi-file) and the links provided on this webpage.

> The easiest way to do it is indeed using an FFMPEG, since its alredy includes some of the most common codecs (if you dont mind extra 30+Mb added to your app). As for wrappers, i used [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/) wrapper in the past and really liked it, because of how simple it is to work with. Here is an example from its docs:

```
// create instance of video reader
VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();

// open video file
reader.Open( "test.avi");

// read 100 video frames out of it
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();

    videoFrame.Save(i + ".bmp")

    // dispose the frame when it is no longer required
    videoFrame.Dispose( );
}

reader.Close();
```