# Getting video duration, frame rate and other properties in c#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, frame, avi, rate

Is there any easy way to get from original video detailed information as duration and frame rate??
I have to divide originalvideo to single frames and to do it I want to use NReco.VideoConverter but I in the API I could not find function which allows me to get video properties. If there is not possibility to do it, can you recommend me other useful .net wrapper to FFMpeg? 
I saw of course [Using FFmpeg in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net)
and [Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net) but there are recommended wrappers which are quite old or have only basic functions. I look wrapper which allows me to get details from original video, divide it to single frames (i need to improve quality) and concat it to new one avi or other file of course with audio with possibility to change paramters(resolution, frame rate etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, it shows a way to get all metadata form a file using Windows Media Format SDK 11: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743789(v=vs.85).aspx