# Convert JPEGs to H264 and stream to my server

Tags: c#, image-processing, h.264

I have a c# app.

At the moment I upload jpegs to my server to be rendered onto client browser to give the appearance of a video.

To save on bandwidth I am considering whether I can convert these jpegs to H264 video format and provide a constant stream to my server.

I have seen example (notably) on this forum that will do this using ffmpeg.

However, the examples show that the video is created and THEN can be uploaded to my server.

The only way I can see this working is to do continuous 'cut off''s of say 15 seconds worth of footage and upload to my server.

Is there a better way?

ADDITIONAL NOTES ABOUT MY APPLICATION

The main point of the application is to allow customers to view motion caught on their CCTV cameras - using IP cameras - via a web browser.
These images HAVE to be MPJEG format.

The other side of the application is that the customer also wants to see live streaming on the browser as well.

Normally, to do this with a high FPS rate and low bandwidth usage the H264 encoder is used.  But, H264 uses predictive encoding which cannot be used for motion 'stills'.

The live streaming I have at the moment is not bad.  But will never rival H264 either in FPS or/and bandwidth.

So, I wanted to see if I can have 2 streams going to my server. One would save motion 'stills' to the hard drive and the other will display the live feed.

To achieve this I would presume I would have to do this 'cut off' at time chosen by me - like 15 seconds.

The better option would be to never have a cut off but pipe the stream to my server.

FFMPEGServer seems to offer this but is not available for Windows OS.

I am unsure how to use FFMPEG to send a 'stream' to my server and then receive it on my server C# code.

Comment: Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net

Comment: @Photon Thanks, I will take the time to look at this :)