# Insert image into video at a specific position for a specific duration

Tags: c#, video-editing

My problem is pretty simple: I need to insert into a short video an image at a specific position that will last from a specified minute of the video to another specified one.

My video actually have a placeholder that is used with online video editing tools, but I would like to do it programmatically.

Many people tak about [DirectShow](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/index.html) but the last update looks to be about 10years ago.

Is this actually possible with c#?

**Note:**

I need to do this automatically without my input, this should work in background for me

Comment: I would just call into third party tool, like ffmpeg.

Comment: @Evk wow didn't know that tool! it looks pretty simple! I think I will need a combination of those two posts: [use ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-overlay-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [call from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527963/using-ffmpeg-in-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), right?

Comment: Take a look at the Accord Framework project (available in nuget packages). Screencast Capture Lite sample: https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Sample-applications#screencast-capture-lite   Beware: the FFmpeg project is GPL-licensed in this solution.

Comment: Pretty much yes. Though I would not use any wrappers and just call ffmpeg directly (via Process.Start).

Comment: FFmpeg license details: http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/md_LICENSE.html

Comment: @Evk probably I am wrong (I don't know this program) but calling it with Process.Start should mean that I can't make the edit automatically but I have to be there and edit it myself, or not?

Comment: thanks @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp, I'm going to have  look! since it is for personal use, I think I don't have to worry to much for licensing, but better check :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @Evk sorry, I try to explain: I have to process the video and add the images without my (user) input. If I start the program ffmpeg, I would need to click something or type some command without the full-automation, right?

Comment: No, it's command-line program. You provide arguments and it does what you say, without any user interaction.

Comment: @Evk oh, wow! thanks! i'll try it