# Is there any readable Tao.FFMPEG how to?

Tags: c#, frameworks, ffmpeg, tao-framework, tao.ffmpeg

So FFmpeg is grate lib and there are some wrappers for it in C#. Tao is one of my choise. But how to use it

0) In general

1) with live http streams

2) with FLV format

There is Tao.FFmpeg help which comes with TAO installl but it is just not for me - I do not get a lot out from there. So I need some richt and clear Blog posts or books on how to use tao  for all 3 of my needs (described above)

Comment: BTW Using google for finding info on TAO ffmpeg  wasnt helpfool=(

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272560/is-out-there-any-code-example-tutorial-on-encoding-video-audio-using-net-tao-ffm

Comment: If you're using FFmpeg, make sure you abide by the terms of the licence; many developers don't.  See: http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Answer (score 0):

Tao.FFMPEG is no longer supported. Your question is possible duplicate of: [Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net) and that has some excellent recommendations.

[Solid FFmpeg ActiveX Wrapper](http://www.ffmpeg-activex.com/)  is probably your best bet, unless you want to write a wrapper yourself.. but if you see the source code of FFMpeg (and the work of Fabrice Bellard a.k.a Gerard Lantau) you'll probably agree there is another developer out there who has written a ten times butter wrapper than either of us could.