# Is out there any code example\tutorial on encoding video\audio using .net Tao.FFmpeg?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, tao.ffmpeg

Is out there any code example\tutorial on encoding video\audio using .net Tao.FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Toa.FFmpege is no longer actively supported or developed. I would recommend you have a look at an alternative like [ffmpegSharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/)