# C# version of mp4parser

Tags: java, .net, video-processing, code-conversion

I am looking to parse mp4 for my .net application. I couldn't find any mp4 parser in .net.

Found [mp4parser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) which is in java.

Please let me know is there any C# version available? if no, is it possible to use mp4parser with .net?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest utilizing FFMPEG to accomplish your task.  More information on using ffmpeg with C# can be found at :

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/rymoore/using-c-ffmpeg-11334

Sourceforge has an example project integrating ffmpeg into a c# application.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/files/

Here ais a stackoverflow discussion relating to c# and ffmpeg.  You may also find this useful.

[Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net)

Comment: thank you, I have already using ffmpeg to convert videos; but, my requirement is to find duration of mp4 video file.