# Cross Platform C# Media API

Tags: c#, .net, mono, ffmpeg

I'm trying to define a VideoFile in mono/.net object such that I can call

```
var file = new VideoFile(filepath);
file.VideoDuration
```

Is there a library (os or commercial) which will work across platforms mono/.net which can provide information such as VideoDuration.  The only though I have had on this currently is to wrap ffmpeg.exe and read the console out-stream.

Comment: If you do end up going the wrap FFMpeg route this question / answer might be useful to you:  Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net

Answer (score 6):

[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) is good option, it's a cross platform multimedia framework. And there are bindings that would meet your needs: access the information you require (length of a video file) via a .NET API: [GStreamerSharp](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/).

Indeed, we actually use it in the [Banshee Project](http://banshee.fm/), a media player written in C# (which is the default music player bundled in Ubuntu).

BTW, GStreamer is architected in a way that codecs are plugins, so you have an abstraction between the internals of them (i.e. ffmpeg) which other plugins could fulfill depending on your licensing/format needs.

Comment: Are you saying than Banshee still uses Gstreamer Sharp now?? I'm porting a windows client app over to mono on linux and i'm looking for a solution to play short audio files. GStreamer Sharp will do it?

Comment: Yes, Banshee uses GStreamerSharp on Windows, and will soon be defaulting to GStreamerSharp on Linux too.