# Embedded video player in C# / Mono / Mac + Windows

Tags: c#, macos, mono, windows-media-player

I've built a text editor application with embedded video/audio support so my users are able to load a video and transcribe simultaniously. Now there are new employees and some of them are using MacOs, so the embedded WMP won't work on their computers.

I've had a look at Banshee, but the project is *so* huge and I'm not that good a programmer. There seem to be no tutorials at all on the Internet on how to implement it, resulting in me getting stuck at this point :-(

Any idea would be heavily appreciated!

Comment: The same answer of this question applies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216462/cross-platform-c-sharp-media-api

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of success using mplayer in my applications.

It has a 'slave' mode, whereby you pass it the handle to the window/control you want it to play in (instead of creating it's own window). You can drive it by piping commands into stdin.

[mplayer slave mode](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt)