# C# video transcoding library

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, rtp, transcoding

I need to transcode video streams using C#.  The streams come in a variety of formats, like `MP4`, `H264`, `H263`, `VP8`.  Is there any library for c# that can transcode a `MemoryStream`?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net

Comment: Questions asking for library recommendation are often closed as not constructive. [See this Meta Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138252/148672) But as Bill's answer to [Best library for xyz](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157224/148672) suggest, asking how to do transcoding instead is perfectly fine and if a library recommendation is the answer that's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [`ffmpeg-sharp`](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) library

> ffmpeg-sharp is a wrapper library over the FFmpeg multimedia suite
>   that provides easy to use wrappers for use in CIL products under both
>   Mono and .NET

Also look at [`SharpFFmpeg`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/)

> SharpFFmpeg is a C# binding of ffmpeg. The goal of SharpFFmpeg is to
>   provide the facility that allows .NET developers to easily create
>   audio and video applications.

And [`MeWiG - MEncoder GUI for Windows`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mewig/?source=navbar)

> MeWiG is a Windows Frontend to the MEncoder (part of MPlayer) using
>   the .NET Framework.You should be able to crop, scale, deinterlace, etc
>   and finally convert almost any digital video-source, without the need
>   for commandline-options.