# How to decode mp3 to wav on Azure WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, naudio

I have a problem with decoding mp3 to wav (or byte array, or pcm stream) using NAudio when my asp.net mvc5 application running on Azure. On the local IIS it works properly. But on the Azure I'm getting "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" when calling Mp3FileReader.
I think it may be cause of missing codecs. How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to make a reference or something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you mark the dlls used for decoding as "copy local"?

Comment: @pollirrata yes, NAudio reference "Copy Local" attribute is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Azure App Service, most likely some of the call would be blocked by [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

you can use Azure Media Service to do the encode/decode work for you
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! But it seems to be too powerful tool for a one simple task. Is there any environment independed libraries for decoding mp3?

Comment: It seems as though Azure Media Service supports WAV as an input format but not for output.

Answer (score 1):

I second Xiaomin on the sandbox point. COM access is blocked in App Service.

That being said, `ffmpeg` works just fine. Process invoke it from your C#.

[image]

**ffmpeg:** https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
A discussion on C# wrappers for ffmpeg here:
[Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net)