# Using ffmpeg in C# WPF app to edit m4b metadata

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I am trying to add functionality to a WPF app to edit the chapter metadata of an m4b file. I was planning of using FFmpeg. I can do it in the command line if I have an existing FFmpeg metadata file with something like

```
ffmpeg -i original.mov -f ffmetadata -i metadata.txt compressed.mp4
```

But I don't know how do do this with a WPF app. Part of the reason that I don't want to just use the command line is that I don't have a metadata file, so I have to parse a cue file and make one on the fly. Also, working on my c# skills. I found some stuff on ffmpeginterop but it looks like that's used if you want to deal with the media stream.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2163036/656243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was doing something similar and found this useful.

mp4chap, part of MP4v2 Library, they have a c# version you can use in your project.
https://github.com/pcwalton/mp4v2
https://www.nuget.org/packages/mp4chap/