# Use FFmpeg in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg in a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010. I want to include the libraries as statically linked files. Simple programs like [libavcodec/api-example.c](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html) compile without error and no linker error appears in the error view when starting them. However, a message box shows up after starting the application, saying that avutil-51.dll is missing. Do you have any hints on how to fix that?

I used the latest dev build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. Then I specified include as additional include directory, avcodec.lib;avfilter.lib;avformat.lib;avutil.lib as additional dependencies and lib as additional library directory.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With FFmpeg you can either:

1. use pre-built .lib/.dll files and your binary produced with Visual Studio will be dependent on av*.dll files
2. compile FFmpeg from source code into static libraries using non-Microsoft compiler, and then link to your Visual Studio project (mind the LGPL/GPL license in this case)

You built your project as per item 1 above. You have to use and redistribute the av*.dll dependent files with your binary to have it working.

"Static" on [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) means that libraries are statically linked into binaries like `ffmpeg.exe`. Do not confuse this with static `.lib` libraries that link into your binary. Zeranoe does not provide such.

On [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) you will find archives like this:

- "Shared" ffmpeg-20120726-git-236ecc3-win32-shared.7z:
- `bin/avcodec-54.dll`
- `bin/avutil-51.dll`
- etc
- "Dev" ffmpeg-20120726-git-236ecc3-win32-dev.7z:
- `lib/avcodec.lib`
- `lib/avutil.lib`

"Shared" archive has FFmpeg built with dynamic link to DLL libraries. "Dev" archive has lib files which you can use in your project to link to them as well in a way that ffmpeg.exe does in shared archive.

So, your Visual Studio project can be as simple as this ([browse full source here](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/FFmpeg/FFmpegApp)):

```cpp
extern "C" 
{
        // NOTE: Additional directory ..\zeranoe.com\dev\include gets to the files
        #include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
}

// NOTE: Additional directory ..\zeranoe.com\dev\lib gets to the files
#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")

// NOTE: Be sure to copy DLL files from ..\zeranoe.com\shared\bin to the directory of 
//       the FFmpegApp.exe binary
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        _tprintf(_T("Trying avcodec_register_all... "));
        avcodec_register_all();
        _tprintf(_T("Done.\n"));
        return 0;
}
```

You will extract "Dev" archive into `dev` subdirectory of Visual Studio project and you will add `dev\include` on the additional include path. This will be sufficient to build the binary, and it will be dependent on `av*.dll`:

[image]

This is when you extract the "Shared" archive, and copy DLLs from its `bin` to the directory of your binary. And your app will work from there:

```
C:\FFmpegApp\Release>FFmpegApp.exe
Trying avcodec_register_all... Done.
```

**20 Jan 2016 UPDATE**: The project in repository is upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 (older VS 2010 code) and checked against current Zeranoe builds. The sample and instructions remain in good standing.

Note that `Win32` builds in Visual Studio assume that you use 32-bit files from Zeranoe. To build 64-bit version, download respective files and set up Visual C++ project respectively, to build `x64` (or, the best, download both, set up both configurations and configure include/lib paths respectively). Failure to match bitness would result in error, mentioned in the comments below.

**20 Jul 2021 UPDATE**: (pulled from comments below) Zeranoe builds are no longer available. A good and officially endorsed alternative is [Windows builds by BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). You will need a `(...)-win64-gpl-shared.zip` or `(...)-win64-lgpl-shared.zip` file for this tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! There are some .dll.a files in the project which I also tried to include as additional includes for the linker. However, there is no avutil-51.dll but only a libavutil.dll.a file. Do I have to get additional dlls or where/how do I have to include them?

Comment: I updated answer above (with correction as for "static" builds). You will need Dev archive to link into your projects, and Shared archive wlil get you missing DLLs.

Comment: I did as you described but I couldn't get it to work (error remains). Where do I have to include the DLLs? I tried to put them in various include paths and copied them to the same folder as the executable. Do I have to do anything with the *.dll.a files in "Dev"?

Comment: I thought I could be giving you wrong advice... but nope, everything is in good standing. See answer above for even more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I followed your detailed description and now it works.

Comment: For MSVC 2012 or earlier these files are needed
https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/

Comment: Absolutely do not forget the `extern "C"`!! I missed it in your example and was tearing my hair out as I couldn't see what I was doing differently.

Comment: I get `Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_register_all referenced in function _wmain M:\Desktop\testeFFmpeg\FFmpegApp.obj FFmpegApp` when I try to run your example...any reasons why?

Comment: @mFeinstein: something is wrong with `avcodec.lib`, not found or wrong path.

Comment: @RomanR. I downloaded it from Zeranoe's latest dev build. Can your try this please? I am days trying to compile this....I think it's MinGW compilation has names with no underscore and maybe different calling conventions. Also they are only static libs, so I wonder if when you made this Answer, if they weren't shared libs for use with the dlls.

Comment: @mFeinstein: checked with VS2013 and latest Zeranoe FFmpeg - the sample remains in good standing

Comment: @RomanR. are you using which build? dev? and which lib? avcodec.lib?

Comment: Have a look at added comments [there](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/FFmpeg/FFmpegApp/FFmpegApp.cpp) to see what is taken from "dev" and what is taken from "shared".

Comment: @RomanR. I still can't get it to compile. Do you mind running [this example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcaluqXbeOraVlwVV9rejNjMzQ/view?usp=sharing)? I added the libraries and everything inside.

Comment: @mFeinstein: You took 64-bit build of FFmpeg, so you need to build Debug/x64 in Visual Studio as well. This builds fine. Or, build Win32 and use 32-bit files from Zeranoe.

Comment: @RomanR. ooohhh hahaha I feel so silly, I am wasting days on this! I can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: @RomanR. do you think I there is any real performance advantages using a x64 lib instead of a x86 one?

Comment: 64-bit builds are, generally, not about performance. Performance might slightly differ through too. The typical problem is that you need bitness [for your DLL] to match bitness of the [EXE] application you are using it with. Second typical problem is that with 64-bit builds you don't have virtual address space constraint, and it might be important since a lot of apps nowadays do hit it.

Comment: I thought 64 bits will help in performance since any 64 bit arithmetic will be done in one instruction.

Comment: So the only reason someone will choose a 64 bit build will be to have more virtual address space?

Comment: Zeranoe builds are no longer available. As of 2021-07-21, a good and officially endorsed alternative is [Windows builds by BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). You will need a `(...)-win64-gpl-shared.zip` or `(...)-win64-lgpl-shared.zip` file for this tutorial.

Comment: Hi, I browsed Windows builds by BtbN, and did not find a dev archive as described here. Nevertheless, I linked the lib in the ./lib directory and copied the .dlls into my project. However, several link error occurred showing unresolved external symbols found in the lib files I linked. Example: ```avformat.lib(tcp.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_closesocket```

Comment: Never mind, I have set another unnecessary linker option that caused the problem.