# Compiling FFMPEG in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I need help compiling  "http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html" using visual studio express 2013.

I followed the solution indicated in "[Use FFmpeg in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio)", however I still get the message "error C1189: #missing -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS / #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

Thanks,

Comment: @ronag How and where?

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Please try it, it should work.

```
#include <math.h>
extern "C" {
    #ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #endif

    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
    #include <libavutil/common.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
    #include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
    #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
}
```

Comment: Why do you include the `extern "C"`? The files can be included from any C file without it, and you can setup a VC project with a C main file.