# Visual C++ linker can't resolve FFmpeg's external symbols

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm making a C++ program and I want to use FFmpeg pre-built for x64, which is a C-compiled library.
I'm using this code in order to include its header:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"

    #pragma comment (lib,"G:/Documents/ffmpeg/lib/avcodec.lib")
    #pragma comment (lib,"G:/Documents/ffmpeg/lib/avformat.lib")
}
```

I'm then calling the symbols like I would do for a normal function, for example with `av_interleaved_write_frame(out->formatContext, &packet);`

However, when I try to compile it with Visual Studio 2015's built-in C++ compiler, I get a lot of error like

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _av_write_trailer referenced in function "void __cdecl closeArenaVideo(struct VideoOutput *)" (?closeArenaVideo@@YAXPAUVideoOutput@@@Z)  Sparta2 c:\Users\Théo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Sparta2\Sparta2\video.obj
```

for basically any of the symbols I'm refering to.

I tried to import everything in Visual Studio, to compile with command-line, to manually put FFmpeg's libraries in the default libraries path, without success.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11701737/868014) and its update at the bottom related to 32/64 lib confusion, it might be your case too.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is indeed the problem! You can make a proper answer if you want to, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical problem which is hard to understand from quoted linker errors is the problem of referencing wrong `.lib` files, esp `Win32` platform libraries in `x64` build and vice versa. The names might be correct, but the set is wrong and then linker takes the `#pragma` references but ignores the content.

You should make sure that your build platform matches the bitness of referenced library files. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701737/868014) has minimalistic project which does build well and you can compare code/references to what you use, and it also mentions bitness problem as well in the very bottom and comments to the answer.