# FFmpeg avformat_open_input not working: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, ffmpeg

This is my first time using FFmpeg.  Every type of media file that I try to open with `avformat_open_input`, returns **"Invalid data found when processing input"**.  I am using 32bit FFmpeg Build Version: 92de2c2.  I setup my VS2015 project according to this answer: [Use FFmpeg in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio).  What could be going wrong with this code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    avcodec_register_all();

    const char* filename = "d:\\a.mp4";
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        char buff[256];
        av_strerror(ret, buff, 256);
        printf(buff);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried another video file? Sometimes this error means the format of input file is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I and tried several different video files and formats including mp4, mkv, avi, mp3.  I know these file work because they are handled no problem when I process them through ffmpeg.exe

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot to call [`av_register_all`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/group__lavf__core.html#ga917265caec45ef5a0646356ed1a507e3), ffmpeg has no demuxer/muxer registered.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    const char* filename = "d:\\a.mp4";
    int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        char buff[256];
        av_strerror(ret, buff, 256);
        printf(buff);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this . still getting same error. i am getting file from ftp. for smb its working fine