# ffmpeg .libs windows visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ffmpeg, lnk2019

I've downloaded the latest version of FFMPEG dev libraries, which include all the .libs etc
I've created an MFC dialogue application in visual studio 2008 and setup all the dependencies as per [Use FFmpeg in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio).

However, I'm getting the lnk2019 issue, unresolved external symbol _avcodec_register_all referenced in funtion...

I included the extern C at the top of my programme and setup the additional included directories...

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!