# Visual Studio can't detect FFmpeg

Tags: python, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 for a Python 3 project that involves using FFmpeg. However, when I try to run my code, I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
```

I have FFmpeg installed and added to my PATH, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Here are the steps I've taken so far to try to fix this:

1. I tried installing the FFmpeg pip package, but it didn't change anything.
2. I searched for solutions on sites like learn.microsoft.com and
   stackoverflow.com, but I haven't been able to find anything that works for me. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701635/use-ffmpeg-in-visual-studio) also didn't answer my question
3. I also asked for help in Visual Studio Code, but I wasn't able to find a solution there either.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, Visual Studio was installing the packages to one interpreter but actually running the code with another.

I changed what interpreter I was using. CTRL+SHIFT+P, then `Python: Select Interpreter`.